# Какова этимология слова "обаяние"?

Tags: этимология

Этот вопрос не дублирует мой предыдущий вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово возникло  в XI–XII веках от древнерусского ***обаяти***  — околдовать словами" от ***баяти*** — говорить.

И первоначальное значение тоже было связано с колдовством: сам процесс или околдованное состояние.

Answer (score 1):

Статьи из ПЦ-СС РЯ Г. Дьяченко удостоверяют, что слова с такой основой известны по древнейшим текстам:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

От глагола баяти, -баj- — корень.